# Inequality about logarithm

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have tried to prove the following inequality:

$$
\left(1+\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^n \gt\frac{n+1}{2}, \mbox{for}\;n\in\{2,3,\ldots\}
$$

which seems to be correct (confirmed by numerical result).

Can anyone give me some help or hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: for what stands $n$ here?

Comment: Are you sure the inequality shouldn't be the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(1+\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^n\gt\frac{n+1}{2}
$$
Let $n=2$, then
$$
\left(1+\frac{\log 2}{2}\right)^2\gt\frac{2+1}{2}
$$
$$
1+\log 2+\frac14(\log 2)^2\gt1+\frac12
$$
Let $n=k+1$, then
$$\left(1+\frac{\log(k+1)}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}\gt\left(1+\frac{\log k}{k}\right)^k+\frac12$$
Applying the induction hypothesis, we have
$$\left(1+\frac{\log k}{k}\right)^k+\frac12\gt\frac{k+1}{2}+\frac12$$
Therefore
$$\left(1+\frac{\log(k+1)}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}\gt\frac{(k+1)+1}{2}$$
Which proves the hypothesis for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I must admit that I should make the first inequality in the inductive step more obvious. I'll update when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give a hint: Since the inequality is claimed to be true for all natural numbers greater than one, I would try a [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). It consists of four steps:

1. You show that the inequality is true for $n = 2$.
2. You assume that th inequality is true for an $n$.
3. You show that the inequality is true for $n + 1$.
4. You conclude that the inequality was shown to be true for all $n \geq 2$.